# Calculating Percentage within MYSQL query based on conditions

Tags: mysql, subquery

hope you can help, this is driving me up the wall

I need to calculate the percentage of times a question has been failed, but this needs to be narrowed down by the geographical area, and product these questions are being asked against.

I have :

```
$CA002 = "( SELECT ROUND(100 *  (SELECT count(CA002Result) from Data_Table where (CA002Result='Fail'))/count(CA002Result),2) from Data_Table) AS 'CA002 %'";
```

Which 'works' but just calculates against the whole set of records as an 'overall'

I'm trying :

```
$CA001 = "( SELECT ROUND(100 *  (SELECT count(CA001Result) from Data_Table where (CA001Result='Fail' AND Area ='$Area'))/count(CA001Result) from Data_Table WHERE (Area='$Area'),2) AS 'CA001 %'";
```

And Also :

```
$CA001 = "( SELECT ROUND(100 * (SELECT count(CA001Result ) from Data_Table where (CA001Result='Fail' AND Product='$product' AND Area='$Area'))      
    /     count(CA001Result WHERE Product = '$product' AND Area='$Area'),2) from Data_Table) AS 'CA001 %'";
```

Also Trying this, but get a MYSQL syntax Error.

```
$CA001 = "( SELECT ROUND(100 *  (SELECT count(CA001Result) from Data_Table where (CA001Result='Fail'))/ (SELECT (count(CA001Result) from Data_Table WHERE (Area='$Area')),2) AS 'CA001 %')";
```

and am just getting errors no matter what I try, I just can't seem to work out what I need to put where.

TRied the below answer:

```
$CA001 = "(SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA001Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA001Result) as 'CA001 %' WHERE  Area='$Area')";

$CA002 = "( SELECT ROUND(100 *  (SELECT count(CA002Result) from Data_Table where (CA002Result='Fail'))/count(CA002Result),2) from Data_Table) AS 'CA002 %'";
```

but am getting the below as an error:

MySQL ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ( SELECT ROUND(100 * (SELECT count(CA002Result) from Data_Table where (CA002Re' at line 1

Any help GREATLY appreciated, thankyou.

Edit - Cracked it using :

```
$CA001 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA001Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA001Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),2) as 'CA001 %'";
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You should include your table structure. Also word wrap your queries to make them easier to read.

Comment: Table structure is the Questions (CA001Result for Example) which will have Pass or Fail written in each record.  Here's there a Product column, and and Area column along with employee names in a different column.  I'm basically trying to work out the total % of Questions failed against how many answered, by People in that area (selected from a POST value) , regarding that Product (also selected from a POST Value).

Comment: Why are you wrapping the queries in ()'s? - it appears to me that is what is causing the exception.

Comment: I'm completely new to this, and got the first snippets from another site, do you not need to use ()'s then?  My very top example works though?  It's just when I need to add in the other subquery bit it goes wrong.  However trying it without wrapping in ()'s seems to kick up a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA001Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA001Result) as 'CA002 %'
FROM Data_Table
WHERE '$product' AND Area='$Area'
```

Comment: Just tried this however still getting an error, have edited questions above to show what I'm getting.

Comment: Ok, I just added a FROM to the query (it was missing) and tried a variation of the query on an existing MySQL database, and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: Excellent! This is  now correctly choosing the product / area for me, just need to round it to 2 decimal places now, I added it in to a similar place to the examples above, but it's kicking up the syntax error again, so maybe that was what was causing my issue, could you advise where / how to put the ROUND in?

Comment: Cracked it :)  put the completed thing in the example above, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing your model, but you should try this pattern:

```
SELECT
    Area,
    Product,
    COUNT(*) as total,
    SUM(CA002Result='Fail') as total_fail,
    SUM(CA002Result='Fail') / COUNT(*) as 'CA002 %'
FROM Data_Table
GROUP BY Area, Product;
```