# Get percentage of column that have value

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to do this:

```
 SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM users WHERE email != '') / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users)
```

But it gave me this error in php `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`, in mysql everything works. Any other solution?

> EDIT : its not exactly like that I had also groups by months, the above query works but the accepted answer solves my error

Comment: try using `select count(your_primary_key)`.. in both the select ...

Comment: You may follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173248/calculating-percentage-within-mysql-query-based-on-conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a single query:

```
SELECT SUM(email != '') / COUNT(*) 
    AS ratio
  FROM users
```

... or, if you need percentage:

```
SELECT 100 * SUM(email != '') / COUNT(*)
    AS percentage
  FROM users
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

`SELECT (SELECT COUNT(your_primary_key) FROM users WHERE email != '') / (SELECT COUNT(your_primary_key) FROM users)`....

this is happening due to number of fields are different in both tables...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as counts
 FROM users 
 WHERE email != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do? If you can calculate the percentage in SQL query, you may follow the link [Calculating Percentage within MYSQL query based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173248/calculating-percentage-within-mysql-query-based-on-conditions)